Do the batteries connected in series drain faster than batteries connected in parallel?
See the following two circuits. The batteries are identical and also the consumer (LED in this case, but we can consider others). We know the series circuit provides double the voltage compared to the parallel. Do the batteries connected in series drain faster then the ones connected in parallel? Do the series batteries provide more energy per time unit compared to the parallel batteries?


The batteries have the same total stored energy, so whether they deplete faster will depend entirely on the rate at which they deliver that energy (power) to their load.
There's one scenario for which neither battery configuration will deplete significantly faster or slower than the other, and that is when the load consumes the same power regardless of the voltage of its supply. Many systems that employ DC-DC converters to take an arbitrary, or variable power supply voltage, and produce a constant voltage output to operate whatever circuitry follows, fall into this category (this does not include linear regulators). Many modern battery-powered appliances use DC-DC converters.
For loads that do not employ DC-DC converters, some analysis is required. The rate at which energy is transferred to the load is called "power", and is therefore a measure of how quickly the batteries are depleted. Power \$P\$ is calculated to be the product of total supply voltage \$V\$ and current \$I\$, so you'll need to know both battery current and voltage.
$$ P = V \times I $$
I'll call an individual battery's voltage \$V_B\$. For batteries in a series configuration, their combined voltage \$V_{SER}\$ will be the sum of the batteries' individual voltages. For instance, three 9V batteries in series provides \$V_{SER}=3 \times V_B=27V\$. Those same batteries connected in parallel will produce the same voltage as an individual one, \$V_{PAR}=V_B=9V\$.
Current is harder to deal with, since that depends entirely on the load, and so to compare the depletion rates of those two different battery configurations, you must also find the current drawn by the load in each configuration.
If the load were purely resistive, with resistance \$R\$, such as a heating element, then the algebra is simple. Using Ohm's law, current \$I\$ is:
$$ I = \frac{V}{R} $$
For the case where all batteries are in parallel:
$$ I_{PAR} = \frac{V_B}{R} $$
Power delivered by batteries connected in parallel, then is:
$$
\begin{aligned}
P_{PAR} &= V_{PAR} \times I_{PAR} \\ \\
&= V_B \times \frac{V_B}{R} \\ \\
&= \frac{{V_B}^2}{R}
\end{aligned}
$$
For \$N\$ batteries connected in series:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{SER} &= N\times V_B \\ \\
I_{SER} &= \frac{V_{SER}}{R} \\ \\
&= \frac{N \times V_B}{R} \\ \\
P_{SER} &= V_{SER} \times I_{SER} \\ \\
&= N\times V_B \times \frac{N \times V_B}{R} \\ \\
&= N^2 \times \frac{{V_B}^2}{R} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Clearly \$P_{SER}\$ is greater than \$P_{PAR}\$ by a factor of \$N^2\$. This tells you that powering a resistive load with \$N=3\$ batteries in series would deplete those batteries \$N^2=9\$ times faster than if they were in parallel. Of course those batteries are also providing 9 times more power to the load, so if the load were just a heating element, it would be much, much hotter.
I would argue that most loads (that aren't DC-DC converters) will draw a current which increases with voltage. It's not hard to see that since batteries in series would therefore supply both increased voltage and increased current, the power they deliver must necessarily be greater, and would consequently drain the batteries more quickly.
This will almost certainly be the case for LEDs too, unless you are using some kind of DC-DC converter with them. Usually you would employ some means of controlling current through the LED, such as a resistor or current regulator. Depending on the technique you use to control LED current, increasing the voltage may cause current to increase also, or at least remain constant. Either way power would be greater, so the series-battery setup would drain faster.
I'll end with the caveat that the correct answer to this question will depend entirely on the load being powered by those batteries. You'd have to perform calculations similar to mine above, for the particular load in question, in order to definitively claim which battery configuration would drain fastest. It's perfectly possible (but uncommon) for a load to reduce its current demand as the voltage across it increases, which could yield a very different conclusion.

To make things simple, lets consider a resistive load instead of an LED.
Battery voltage = V (each battery)
Resistor value = R
Battery energy = E (each battery)
Case 1: Batteries in series
Current = 2V/R
Power = 4V^2 / R
Total energy of batteries = 2E
Case 2: Batteries in parallel
Current = V/R
Power = V^2 / R
Total energy of batteries = 2E
Power is energy per time. So a series battery circuit is drawing four times the power as compared to a parallel circuit. Hence, series batteries will drain faster.

Batteries in series, or in parallel, don't drain.   They power a load.
The answer to battery lifetime depends on the nature of the load.
With some loads, the two cases give identical battery life.
With an LED as a load, there's MUCH higher power output (and probably
an overheated LED) for the series-connect case because
current is exponential in the applied voltage; double a 1.5V
(two alkaline cells in parallel) source to 3.0V (two alkaline cells
in series) and the LED current goes up by many orders of magnitude.

@RayButterworth The ideal diode follows Shockley's diode equation, , I= I_s x exp(q_E x V /(K_b x T).   Unless the LED is far from ideal (internal resistance) exponential is correct.
